# Modify to have a configurable number of stars "*"

Tags: c++

I manage to print out the output for the pattern of stars I wanted but now I want to have a configurable number of stars "*" and automatically calculated corresponding number of rows.

I have tried several ways but the output seems to be off. If there is better way to display the output please guide me.

```
int i, j, k,l;
k = 1;
l = 11;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
        for (j = 0; j < k ; j++)
        {
            cout << "* ";
        }
        cout << "- ";
        k += 2;
        for (j = 0; j < l; j++)
        {
            cout << "* ";
        }
        l -= 2;
    cout << endl;
      }

* - * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * - * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * - * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * - * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * - * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * - *
```

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Then show your approach. It seems to me that simple double loop `1...n` with `if(i,j==n/2)` could suffice.

Comment: The other approach is to just use `std::string` in a loop.  Basically a 3 line function, if you know how to use the `std::string` constructor that takes a count and a character to print.  Also, are we to assume that the number of stars is always odd?

Comment: yes they are odd but what if the user input to set the number of stars how should I code it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of rows is given, then the resulting number of columns can easily be calculated. Look at your pattern then you will see that the number of necessary coulmns is number of rows times 2 + 1.

Here one possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the number of rows for the pattern: ";

    unsigned int numberOfRows{ 0 };
    std::cin >> numberOfRows;

    // Number of columns is always number of rows * 2 + 1
    unsigned int numberOfColumns{ numberOfRows * 2 + 1 };
    unsigned int positionOfDash{ 1 };
    // Print the pattern
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
        for (unsigned int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; ++col) {
            // Output dash in desired column or else star
            std::cout << (col == positionOfDash ? '-' : '*') << ' ';
        }
        positionOfDash += 2;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note: Of course there are tons of other possible solutions . . .

Comment: col == positionOfDash ? '-' : '*' the "?" indicate what actually ...sorry for asking

Comment: The ?: operator is a tenary operator. In the first part, it checks a condition. So it checks, if the content of the col variable is equal to the content of the poistionOfDash variable (Answering the question: Shall I print a dash now). If this is true, than the result of ths ?: construct ist the part behind the "?", so the dash and if not then it is the part behind the ":", so the '*'.  It is similar to an if then else statement, but in the form of an expresssion. So you can directly work with the result.